When doing SSH through an intermediary server what are the differences between Local Port-forwarding and Jump Host?
To SSH to Server-B through an intermediary (Server-A), what are the differences between the following two approaches and which one is better?
Local port-forwarding
ssh -L 2222:server-b:22 root@server-a
ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222

Jumphost
ssh -J root@server-a root@server-b


You can answer yourself that question by reading the man page - Skip to the option "ProxyJump"...

@Martin information in the man page is outdated. Surprise!

Past OpenSSH versions did it exactly like that, so there was no difference.
Modern version do ProxyJump slightly differently: runs ssh -W [target]:22 gateway, and uses that as a ProxyCommand, but the practical difference is none, just uses TCP/IP less and, hopefully, has smaller overhead.
